# Fading in and out with ES6 and CSS3

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a function that I'm trying to create the loops through an array to update a div's innerHTML with JavaScript. I was hoping to set the opacity to 0 and then 1 between setting the new data each time, without using jQuery's fadeIn() and fadeOut().

Here is what I have so far. I think I'm very close, but not sure what I'm doing that's slightly off.

Thanks!

```
 slide(index, tweets, element) {
    let self = this;

    element.innerHTML = data[index].text;
    element.style.opacity = 1;

    setTimeout(() => {
        index++;
        element.style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(self.slide(index, data, element), 2000);
    }, 5000);
}
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention I'm banking on CSS3 for animation by adding a class to my div that changes with this:

```
transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use CSS 3 for this? Since you specified ES6, I assume you're targeting modern browsers.

Comment: I am using CSS3. Sorry, I didn't specify that. I'm using a 'transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;', but I can't for the life of me figure out how to trigger it before and after setting the innerHTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how the code you provided relates to the problem at hand, but here's a simple demo on how to fade out, change the text and then fade back in.

You should be able to expand on this for your needs.

```js
var d = document.querySelector("div");

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  d.classList.add("hidden");
});

var i = 0;

d.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    i++;
    this.innerHTML = "SUCCESS! ---> " + i;
  }
  this.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

div.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>LOADING...</div>
```

It just adds the `hidden` class to trigger the fade out and it binds a `transitionend` handler to change the text and remove the class for the fade in.

Comment: I believe this solution provides better UX than relying entirely on JS timeouts and intervals. Good answer!

Comment: So the only problem is that I'm not clicking on anything. It's just an infinite loop that fades in and out. I'll try to do something like this though..

Comment: @eightonrose: You'll just add the class on load (or whenever) to start it and have the `transitionend` handler either remove or add the class as needed. Actually, you can use `classList.toggle("hidden")`.

Comment: Okay - so I tried this out, and for some reason my code isn't even hitting the event listener. 'transitionend' is there to run after a CSS transition, correct?

Comment: @eightonrose: That's correct. Any errors in your browser's developer console?